# Hide symbolic link files from SublimeText 2 Project sidebar

Tags: sublimetext2

On the Project sidebar, I want to exclude my symbolic link files from that sidebar.

- `file_exclude_patterns`: [`*.jpg`, `*.gif`, `*.png`, `*.xib`, `*.sublime-*`],
- `folder_exclude_patterns`: [`img`]

How can I exclude Symbolic link files from Project?

Including `*@` to `file_exclude_patterns` doesn't work.

Comment: To make other directory including only symlink files, I don't need to remove the symlink file's exhibition from ST sidebar. Thank you to watch this tiny thread.